# Get a list of objects in tastypie (in another view)

Tags: django, tastypie

I'm trying to get a tastypie response to use in another view. I've seen [the recipe in the cookbook](http://django-tastypie.readthedocs.org/en/latest/cookbook.html#using-your-resource-in-regular-views). Problem is, I'd like to get the list view. In my case, `/api/v1/source/`. Here's what I've got so far:

```
sr = SourceResource()
objs = sr.get_object_list(request) # two objects returned
bun = sr.build_bundle(data=objs, request=request)

jsondata = sr.serialize(None, sr.full_dehydrate(bun), 'application/json')
```

Of course this all falls apart. `bun.data` doesn't have the required characteristics (a single object). So, has anyone done this successfully? How is it done?

Comment: Simply look at the tastypie code in `ModelResource`. There is already a well defined code path for serialization, hydration/dehydration and deserialization for both lists and single objects. If I remember right there are helper functions that build lists of bundles.

Comment: Yeah, total brain fart on my part not to look at the source. I believe you're referring to [this](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L1051). I'll accept your answer if you post one.

Comment: Nah, you should post your own answer once you figure out how to exactly do it so others can benefit too. Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's what I've come up with. I don't especially like that both the request and the QueryDict are copied, but I can't think of anything else at the moment, other than copying big portions of [the tastypie code](https://github.com/toastdriven/django-tastypie/blob/master/tastypie/resources.py#L1051).

```
from copy import copy

from django.views.generic import TemplateView

from incremental.sources.resources import SourceResource
resource = SourceResource()

class AppView(TemplateView):
    'Base view for the Source parts of the app'
    template_name = 'sources/base.html'

    def get_context_data(self, **data):
        'get context data'
        tmp_r = copy(self.request)
        tmp_r.GET = tmp_r.GET.copy()
        tmp_r.GET['format'] = 'json'

        data.update({
            'seed': resource.get_list(tmp_r).content
        })
        return data
```

Comment: This is a great solution. I fought attribute errors using get_obj_list and full_dehydrate for hours before stumbling on this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

In order to avoid the request copying stuff, you can set json as the default format, for instance in your Resource you can overload the following method:

```
SourceResource(Resource):
  def determine_format(self, request):
    return "application/json"
```